# @at-root inside a nested partial doesn't work

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I have a .scss file like this:

```
#b-content-container {

    @import "_reset.scss";
    @import "_layout.scss";
    @import "_style.scss";

    @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 999px) {
        @import "_768.scss";
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
        @import "_320.scss";
    }

    @media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {
        @import "_480.scss";
    }

}
```

Inside `_layout.scss`:

```
@at-root {
    @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300);
    @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:700);
    @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:900);
    @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400);
    @import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Vollkorn'; 
}

/* ... rest of styling follows */
```

Normally, the @imports would be stripped by SASS because they're not being included on the root of the document, but from what I understand, @at-root should prevent this by including those rules at the top of the compiled .css. However, this doesn't happen, and the rules are just left out as normal.

This works fine:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:700);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:900);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400);
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Vollkorn'; 

#b-content-container {

    @import "_reset.scss";
    @import "_layout.scss";
    @import "_style.scss";

    @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 999px) {
        @import "_768.scss";
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
        @import "_320.scss";
    }

    @media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {
        @import "_480.scss";
    }

}
```

As does this:

```
#b-content-container {

    @at-root {
        @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300);
        @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:700);
        @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:900);
        @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400);
        @import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Vollkorn'; 
    }

    @import "_reset.scss";
    @import "_layout.scss";
    @import "_style.scss";

    @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 999px) {
        @import "_768.scss";
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
        @import "_320.scss";
    }

    @media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {
        @import "_480.scss";
    }

}
```

It's only when placed inside the partial that the font import doesn't work at all. Is there a way to fix this?